# How to get multi-display on guest Ubuntu on host MacOS?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, qemu

My company provides iMac for us, but I want to work on Ubuntu instead. I am trying to run Ubuntu 20.04 with QEMU. I have to hardware screens. I want two virtual QEMU screens so I can put one on each physical screens. May I know how can I do that?

Below is the script I run QEMU.

> qemu-system-x86_64 
> -enable-kvm 
> -no-user-config 
> -nodefaults 
> -show-cursor 
> -M pc-q35-3.1,accel=hvf,usb=off,vmport=off 
> -cpu Penryn,kvm=on,vendor=GenuineIntel 
> -smp 4,sockets=1,cores=2,threads=2 
> -m 4096 
> -realtime mlock=off 
> -rtc base=utc,driftfix=slew 
> -drive file=/Users/rogerleung/ubuntu.qcow2,if=none,format=qcow2,id=disk0 
> -device virtio-blk-pci,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1,drive=disk0 
> -netdev user,id=net0 
> -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2 
> -device virtio-keyboard-pci,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x3 
> -device virtio-tablet-pci,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x4 
> -device virtio-vga,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x5 
> -cdrom /Users/rogerleung/Downloads/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso -boot d

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: sorry no.......